# ManyToMany on part of composite key

Tags: java, hibernate

First of all: I know there are plenty of similar questions here, but I've read most of them and all seems to adress slightly different issues, and no one had a satisfactory answer... So I still hope someone knows how to handle my problem...

Simply said, I have an entity which has an composite key and I want to join a collection of other entities on part of this composite key. Unfortunately hibernate forces me to include the other part of the composite key into the join, leading to useless large join tables (>20m rows for 250 distinct value sets...). Therefore I want to exclude the unecessary part of the key from the join.

Entity sketches:

```
public class A {
    @Id
    int i_am_A;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "i_am_A",name="A_i_am_A")
    Set<AB> abs;
}

public class B {
    @Id
    int i_am_B;

    @Id
    int myLanguage;

    ...
}

public class AB {

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    A myA;

    @Id
    int myB

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColum(name="myB")
    Collection<B> bs;

    @Basic 
    String value

}
```

So this is basically `A` having a relationship with `B` which can have a certain value, which is stored in `AB`. One anomaly is, that `B` exists in multiple languages and `AB` should point to all of them.

Does anyone know how to make this with Hibernate (without remodeling the Db... if possible. I know there might be better designs, but there are quite a few rows in this schema now...) ?

Comment: I think the issue is in your model, shouldn't it be `A <- AB -> B <-C`, with `C` being the multiple traslations of `B`?

Comment: @SJuan76 I feared this might be the only feasible solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by changing the database design according to @SJuan76 comment